# How to swtich the state of workitem with tfs Java sdk

Tags: java, tfs

I try to swtich the state of a workitem from "New" to "Active" like follows:

```
   WorkItemCollection co = tpc.getWorkItemClient().query("select xxxxxx...");
   WorkItem newWorkItem = co.getWorkItem(0);
   newWorkItem.getFields().getField(CoreFieldReferenceNames.STATE).setValue("Active");
```

but there is error reported like this :

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field id [10112] does not exist in this collection (wi=5789377,size=9)
```

Comment: it would be easier to diagnose if we saw how the classes were defined

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's something wrong with this method or this method doesn't support Azure Devops Server 2019U1 since this package is [last published in 2018](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases).

My Test code:

```
public class HelloJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        URI serverURI = null;
        try {
            serverURI = new URI("xxxxxxxx");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("xxx","xxx");
        TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(serverURI, credentials);
        tpc.authenticate();
        WorkItemClient myClient = tpc.getWorkItemClient();
        WorkItemCollection myWorkitemCollection = myClient.query("SELECT [System.Id],[System.WorkItemType],[System.State] FROM workitems");
        //Get workItem Task1
        WorkItem myWorkItem = myWorkitemCollection.getWorkItem(0);
        FieldCollection myFieldCollection = myWorkItem.getFields();
        Field myField = myFieldCollection.getField(CoreFieldReferenceNames.STATE);
        //Get workItem Task2
        WorkItem myWorkItem2 = myWorkitemCollection.getWorkItem(1);
        FieldCollection myFieldCollection2 = myWorkItem2.getFields();
        Field myField2 = myFieldCollection2.getField(CoreFieldReferenceNames.STATE);
        
        System.out.println(myField.getValue());
        System.out.println(myField2.getValue());
        
        myField2.setValue(myField.getValue()); //Where the error occurs.
        
        System.out.println(myField.getValue());
        System.out.println(myField2.getValue());
    }
}
```

The Result:
[image]

The `setValue()` method will throw exception even when I'm trying to set Task1's `state` with Task2's `state`.

A strange thing is that it won't throw error if I give the current state as input... (If task1's state is `To Do`, it won't throw error for xx.setValue("To Do"). If I change the state to `Doing` via web portal, then the code throws error if I enter `To Do` next time!!!)

So I think you have to report this issue to the team of the sdk [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues) to get a fix or share your feedback since maybe it just doesn't work for new Azure Devops Server 2019.